# Creating object / loading from DB - Factory pattern and validation in setters?

Tags: oop, validation, design-patterns

I have a question what would be the best approach when object could by created in many ways.

Let's say we have:

```
class User {

    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $surname;
    private $login;

    public function setId($id) {
      $id = (int) $id;
      if (!$id) {
        throw new Exception("Wrong ID"); 
      }
      $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
      $this->name = trim($name);
      if (strlen($name) < 5) {
        throw new Exception("Name is to short");
      }
    }

    public function setSurname($surname) {
      $this->surname = trim($surname);
      if (strlen($surname) < 5) {
        throw new Exception("Surname is to short");
      }
    }

    public function setLogin($login) {
      /* some login validation */
      $this->login = $login;
    }    


    /* and other methods */

}
```

No I could use this in several ways:

**1. Create new user and save it in DB :**

```
$User = (new User)
  ->setName("John")
  ->setSurname("Kent")
  ->setLogin("JohnK");

$UserSaver = (new UserSaver($User))->save();
```

**2. Load user from DB**

```
class UserFactory {

  public function createById($userId, $db) {
    $row = $db->GetRow("SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id = {$db->qstr($userId}");
    $User = (new User)
      ->setId($row['id'])
      ->setName($row['name'])
      ->setSurname($row['surname'])
      ->setLogin($row['login']);
    return $User;
  }
}

$User = UsersFactory::createByID(7, $db);
```

But my question is about validation in setters. Should it be there?
It could cause a problem when fetching record from database when for example the login is too short (stored erlier by other application). Then an `Exception` would be thrown.

I could:

1. Move validation to separate function **$this->validate()** but I thought that better practice is to detect wrong data as soon as possible.
2. Modify setters by adding second parameter: **function setLogin($login, $validate=true)** and then in UsersFactory do (new User)->setLogin($row['login'], **false**)
3. use inheritance insted of factory to skip setters.

Like this:

```
class UserFromDB extends User () {

  public function __construct($userId, $db) {
    $row = $db->GetRow("SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id = {$db->qstr($userId}");
    $this->id = $row['id'];
    $this->name = $row['name'];
    $this->surname = $row['surname'];
    $this->login =  $row['login'];
  } 

}
```

I will be grateful for suggestions for best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options in order of personal preference.

### 1. **Enforce your policy upon your database.**

Does your database contain data that does not comply to your policies? If so, then why not enforce that policy and clean up your database. Detect all data that does not conform to the policy and come up with some migration plan. This solves your problem and cleans up your data at the same time. If for some reason you don't want to do this you might want to question yourself if your policy is actually any good.

Assuming the above is impossible I would recommend one of either two approaches:

### 2. **CQRS approach**

The Command Query Responsibility Separation pattern is a pretty clean way to avoid these kind of problems. The basic idea is that you create a class that is used for your database writes and a class for database reads. Meaning that you would have to create another class next to your existing user class that is used for reads (UserReadModel would be an appropriate name in CQRS terminology).

CQRS allows you to write robust (domain driven) code. For example, instead of having an integer id. You might make an Id class that can only hold valid id's (for example positive integers). Instead of passing the username an integer id you can thus pass it an Id id. You then don't need to validate anymore at the aggregate level or using a separate validator nor are invalid Id's an option. Other classes can thus benefit from the same validation. Passing Id's instead of integers your code cannot go wrong. Of course your read model can still use integers.

Read up about domain driven design, immutable classes and CQRS if you'd like to know more. These techniques properly combined can be the basis for very robust code.

### 3. **The validate method approach.**

Your first suggestion. This approach allows you to keep your code, but have it both ways. Problem is however that it does not force the user of your class to call the validate method. You could of course force your database layer to always call this method on all classes before persistence, but usually that is a bit too late in the process. Furthermore you will need some way of inferring from validation errors which fields are at fault.

Your validation parameter approach allows your object to become half valid if validation is skipped on one property and not on the next. You would therefore still need a validate method to ensure that the class is fully valid. It is therefore a variation of the same approach. This approach has one other problem: you can not ensure that all setter methods (in the future) will have this boolean parameter. This makes it very hard to generalize upon.

One clean way of doing this would be to inject a user validator class into your user class. The validate method then delegates validation to the validator class. To ensure that a user class always has a validator, instead of creating a user class directly using the new keyword you can use a factory that creates your user class with the appropriate validator class. You can have a strict validator for database inserts and updates and a weak validator or no validator at all for database selects. One advantage to this approach is that this pattern is reusable for other classes.

If you want validation to happen at the moment the setter is called you could create an aggregate of validators. Meaning you could bind a "name validator" to the surname and first name property in your "user validator". The user validator would thus become an aggregate of field validators. This would allow you to trigger validation on a specific field or input at the set moment.